# How to dynamic translate text file using parameter to the ngx-translate in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to use the dynamic text translate in `angular` and `ngx-translate`.

This is my component :

```
export class ShareErrorComponent implements OnInit ,AfterViewInit {

@Input("form") from: FormGroup
@Input("field") fieldName: string;
@Input("nicename") nicename: string;
param: any;
constructor() { }

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.param = { value:this.nicename }
}

fieldErrors(field: string) {
    let controlState = this.from.controls[field];
    return (controlState.dirty || controlState.touched) ? controlState.errors : null;
  }
}
```

and this is my `html` code :

```
  <mat-error *ngIf="fieldErrors(fieldName).required">
   {{ "SHARED_VALIDATE.REQIERD" | translate: param }}
 </mat-error>
```

and this is my translate file :

```
       SHARED_VALIDATE: {
        REQIERD: ' Reqied Fill the {{value}}  '
    },
```

but when i need to translate dynamic it show me this :
`Reqied Fill the {{value}}`

**How can I dynamic translate in my text file?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 {{ "SHARED_VALIDATE.REQIERD" | translate: {value: nicename} }}
```

Spacing is important for object bracket and interpolation bracket